# How can I have my program read updates that it has just made to a text file?

Tags: python, sorting

I am brand new to Python (just started it 5 hours ago) but I have about a year of experience with Java. Anyways, the first program I wanted to make would create a sort of 'log book' of names/Birthdays. It prompts the User for the number of entries, then the names and birthdates. It is fairly simple and works fine. Each time you run the Program it appends the new Names/Birthdates, to the text file so The previous names/birthdates remain intact and the new ones appear at the end. However I wanted to be able to sort these entries by last name. I successfully create a way to sort them by last name (again its not to complex) however It only works if It is its own separate program. If i place the code at the end of my original program, It will sort as expected, however it will not sort any of the new entries made in the program, only the entries from the last time the program was run. I did close the file and re-open it in the code after the entries were made, however it still will not recognizes the changes made. Because Both programs function properly on their own, what do I need to do in order to implement these two pieces of code in the same program? Alternatively, would there be a way to run the second program from the first program?

Here is my programs code (BirthDates.txt is the text file were the entries are stored):

```
#IDLE 1.2.4
#Begin Entries      
fileobja=open("BirthDates.txt","a")
dates=int(raw_input("Number of entries to add:"))
count=0
while count<dates:
    fileobja.write("*NEW ENTRY*")
    firstName=raw_input("Enter user's first name:")
    lastName=raw_input("Enter user's last name:")
    DOB=raw_input("Enter user's date of birth (MM/DD/YYYY):")
    print lastName+","+firstName+"\n"+DOB
    fileobja.write("\n")
    fileobja.write(lastName+", "+firstName+"\n")
    fileobja.write("("+DOB+")"+"\n"+"__________\n")
    #print "dates=",dates
    #print "count=",count
    count=count+1
    #print "count=",count
    fileobja.close
    #End Entries
```

This is the second Program:

```
#Begin Sorter
fileobjr=open("Birthdates.txt","r")
fileList=[]
tempString=""
tempStringCount=0
for line in fileobjr:
    tempString="".join(line[0:])
    #print "tempString="+tempString
    fileList.append(tempString)
    tempStringCount=tempStringCount+1
fileobjr.close
fileListLength=len(fileList)
#print fileListLength
chunks=(fileListLength)/4
sortCount=1
tempList=[]
while sortCount<fileListLength:
    templine=fileList[sortCount]+fileList[sortCount+1]
    tempList.append(templine)
    sortCount=sortCount+4
writeCount=0
tempList.sort()
fileobjw=open("BirthDates.txt","w")
while writeCount<chunks:
    #print tempList[writeCount]
    fileobjw.write("*NEW ENTRY*\n")
    fileobjw.write(tempList[writeCount])
    fileobjw.write("__________")
    fileobjw.write("\n")
    writeCount=writeCount+1
fileobjw.close
#End Sorter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
fileobja.close
```

… and a few similar lines.

You're not *calling* the `close` method, you're just referencing it as a value. So, the file doesn't get closed, which means it doesn't get flushed, which means anything you've written to it may not be available to read yet.

To fix it, just call the method:

```
fileobja.close()
```

---

As a side note, it's usually easier to use a `with` statement, which takes care of closing the file when you exit the block inside it. (It's like a magic try/finally.) Instead of this:

```
f = open('foo', 'a')
do_stuff(f)
do_more_stuff(f)
# ...
f.close()
```

Do this:

```
with open('foo', 'a') as f:
    do_stuff(f)
    do_more_stuff(f)
    # ...
```